# how do move up in the hierarchy to find top level manager?

Tags: c#

I am trying to find top level manager for a employee in multiple level hierarchy.

What I have tried gives me immediate manager but not the top most manager.

```
public Employee GetManager(Employee employee)
{
    Employee topManager = new Employee();

    Stack<Employee> managers = new Stack<Employee>();

    if (employee.ManagerId == null)
    {
        topManager = employee; //CEO ---
    }
    else
    {

        using (var context = new EmployeeContext())
        {
            var manager = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == employee.ManagerId);
            managers.Push(manager);
            GetManager(manager);
        }

        topManager = managers.Peek();
    }
    return topManager;
}
```

Comment: You could pass the stack to the method. Right now you're creating a new stack every time you recurse the method. What you want instead is for each recursive call to use the same stack.

Comment: If you want to move and up and down, then don't use a stack (Thats a LIFO) data sctructure, use  something like a `List<T>`

Comment: The add PARENT into your classes so you can move up the hierarchy easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always returning the immediate manager, since in every recursive call you are creating a new stack that's gonna be filled with the immediate manager of the function argument employee.

If you really want to use recursion, you need to make `managers` a varible that isn't initialized every time the recursive call is made, so something like this:

```cs
public Employee GetManager(Employee employee)
{
    Stack<Employee> managers = new Stack<Employee>();

    BuildManagerStack(employee);
    return managers.Peek();

    void BuildManagerStack(Employee e)
    {
        if (employee.ManagerId == null)
        {
            managers.Push(e);
        }
        else
        {
            using (var context = new EmployeeContext())
            {
                var manager = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == employee.ManagerId);
                managers.Push(manager);
                BuildManagerStack(manager);
            }
    }
}
```

I encourage you to try and solve this problem without using recursion: you'll get a cleaner, more readable and more efficient solution :)

Comment: Is there a way to do so? I know if I could create a table that holds topmost manager and employee I can look up that table. to find the manager. But is there another alternative way to do it?

Comment: i made little change in the code. 
using (var context = new EmployeeContext())
                    {
                        var manager = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == e.ManagerId);

                        if (manager.ManagerId != null)
                        {
                            managers.Push(manager);
                            BuildManagerStack(manager);
                        }
                    }
Thank you sir.

Comment: the easiest way would be to have a field `Employee manager` inside Employee, so that you can easily make this look up like this
`Employee m = employee;  while (m.manager != null) m = m.manager;`
then `m` will be the top-level manager :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a loop and be like:

```
Employee targetManager = employee;
while(targetManager.managerid != null) 
    targetManager = context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == targetManager.ManagerId);
```